# Event on LinearLayout in ListView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listview

I try to get data which is in a `LinearLayout` which is himself in a `ListView`.
So , in my logic, i put an id on the `LinearLayout`, and i add an `OnToucheListener`.
But when i run the app the application quits unexpectedly.

I would like to get the `TexTview` which is in the `LinearLayout` , for after to allow of change data in an `AlertDialog`.

I implements my `ListView` with a `SimpleAdapter` in `onPostExecute()` of my `AsyncTask`, so until now, all works, but i don't know how to get the element(textview) of the linearLayout who is my listView..

So, it's my code to try to get the linearLayout with AlertDialog to allow to change data.

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View alertDialogView = factory.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_divers, null);


    LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test);
    linear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(listview.this);       
            adb.setView(alertDialogView);
            adb.setTitle("Divers");             
            adb.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);            
            adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    EditText et = (EditText)alertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.EditText1);

                }
            });

            adb.setNegativeButton("Annuler", null);
            //on affiche la boite de dialogue
            adb.show();
        }
    });
```

And it's my listView xml file. (I pet in red color to better see where is my linearLayout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.56"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/collector_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="> B10954-1"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/adress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="AIDER BOURGOGNE 14 Rue de la Breuchillière 21000 DIJON "
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/depose"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_code"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="3 F50D - 2 C50HD - 3 F50D - 2 C50HD - 4 BA300 - 5CE2 - 4F30E"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.75"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/border" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/begin_hour"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="07:30-12:30 "
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/end_hour"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="14:00-19:00"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/ordre"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/order"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:text="2"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/tpsarret"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/downtime"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:text="2 min"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

Below, the linearLyout in question with id : test ---------------------------------

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.5" 
            android:background="@drawable/linear_option"
            android:clickable="true"               
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:weightSum="2" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fax"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="03 80 91 03 03 "
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text=" 06 43 66 53 16"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/crayon_icon" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/divers"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/miscellaneous"
                android:layout_width="333dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

End of the linearLayout in question ----------------------------------------------------

<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:background="@drawable/linear_option"
            android:clickable="true"  
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/crayon_icon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/infosco"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/infos"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="118dp"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="73dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/editer_doc" >

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, there are many `LinearLayout` parent. So when i touche the layout with id = test, i want to get  the textView with id : miscellaneous and allow to change it.

I hope that you will understand.

EDIT 1 :

```
02-12 08:45:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9076): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 08:45:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9076): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start              activity ComponentInfo{com.main/com.main.listview}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-12 08:45:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9076):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
02-12 08:45:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9076):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
02-12 08:45:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9076):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-12 08:45:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9076):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
02-12 08:45:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9076):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-12 08:45:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9076):     at  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-12 08:45:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9076):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-12 08:45:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9076):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 08:45:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9076):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-12 08:45:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9076):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-12 08:45:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9076):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-12 08:45:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9076):     at  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-12 08:45:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9076): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-12 08:45:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9076):     at  com.main.listview.onCreate(listview.java:68)
02-12 08:45:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9076):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-12 08:45:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9076):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-12 08:45:54.370: E/AndroidRuntime(9076):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
```

EDIT 2 :

```
public class listview extends Activity {

private ListView maListViewPerso;   
ImageButton imgButton;
Boolean isConnected;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color
            .parseColor("#000000")));

    maListViewPerso = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewperso);
    isConnected = isOnline(); 

    getData(isConnected);

     //On instancie notre layout en tant que View
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View alertDialogView = factory.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_divers, null);


    LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test);
    linear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(listview.this);       
            adb.setView(alertDialogView);
            adb.setTitle("Divers");             
            adb.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);            
            adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    EditText et = (EditText)alertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.EditText1);

                }
            });

            adb.setNegativeButton("Annuler", null);
            //on affiche la boite de dialogue
            adb.show();
        }
    });
```

my listeView load whend getData() is called. (this function call an Asynctask and fill a Hashmap who fill the listView with SimpleAdapter)

EDIT 3 :

```
package com.main;


import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.pdf.GetViewPDF;

public class listview extends Activity {

private ListView maListViewPerso;   
ImageButton imgButton;
Boolean isConnected;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color
            .parseColor("#000000")));

    maListViewPerso = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewperso);
    isConnected = isOnline(); 

    getData(isConnected);
    setdivers();




}

public void setdivers(){
     //On instancie notre layout en tant que View
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View alertDialogView = factory.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_divers, null);


    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test);
    layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(listview.this);       
            adb.setView(alertDialogView);
            adb.setTitle("Divers");             
            adb.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);            
            adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    EditText et = (EditText)alertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.EditText1);

                }
            });

            adb.setNegativeButton("Annuler", null);
            //on affiche la boite de dialogue
            adb.show();
        }
    });
}

public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Action Désactivée", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //              getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
    //              getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
}   

public void GoToPDF(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GetViewPDF.class);
    startActivity(intent);          
}
public void getData(Boolean isConnected){

    if(isConnected){
        asyncTask asynchrone_task_tournee = new asyncTask(listview.this, maListViewPerso);
        asynchrone_task_tournee.execute();  

    }else{
        //J'initialise toutes les variables
        JSONArray jArray = null;
        JSONObject json_data=null;     
        HashMap<String, String> map;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItem = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();         
        InputStream is = null;      
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];

        //je récupère le fichier .txt de donner JSON dans le repertoir asset
        AssetManager am = listview.this.getAssets();
        try {
            is = am.open("donnees_tourne.txt");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        //Je lis le fichier .txt
        try {
                Reader reader = null;
                int n;
                try {
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
                    while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) 
                    {
                        writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
                    }


                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {                  
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {                   
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } finally {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {                   
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        //recuperation des donnees json dans jsonString
        String jsonString = writer.toString();

        Log.i("JSON_NOT_connected",jsonString);

        //traitement du json dans le tableau json JSONArray
        try {
            jArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           

        //Insertion des données json dans un Hashmap
        for(int i=0;i < jArray.length();i++)
        {               
            try {

                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("collector_id", json_data.getString("collector_id"));
                map.put("adress", json_data.getString("adress"));
                map.put("product_code", json_data.getString("product_code"));
                map.put("begin_hour", json_data.getString("begin_hour"));
                map.put("end_hour", json_data.getString("end_hour"));
                map.put("order", json_data.getString("order"));
                map.put("downtime", json_data.getString("downtime"));
                map.put("fax", json_data.getString("fax"));
                map.put("tel", json_data.getString("tel"));
                map.put("miscellaneous", json_data.getString("miscellaneous"));
                map.put("infos", json_data.getString("infos"));

                listItem.add(map);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }     
        }

        SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter (listview.this, listItem, R.layout.list_type_tournee,
                //noms donnés en clé dans le Hashmap 
                new String[] {"collector_id", "adress","product_code","begin_hour",
                              "end_hour","order","downtime","fax",
                              "tel","miscellaneous","infos"}, 
                //variables textview dans la list_type_tournee.xml            
                new int[] {R.id.collector_id, R.id.adress,R.id.product_code,R.id.begin_hour,
                           R.id.end_hour,R.id.order,R.id.downtime,R.id.fax,
                           R.id.tel,R.id.miscellaneous,R.id.infos});

        maListViewPerso.setAdapter(mSchedule);



    }


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.point_menu, menu); 
    menu.getItem(0).setTitle(UtilClass.stringNow());
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_now:
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_login:
        Intent activiteU = new Intent(listview.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(activiteU);
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_tour_inf:
        Intent activiteT = new Intent(listview.this, TourActivity.class);
        activiteT.putExtra("userid", 10);
        startActivity(activiteT);
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_point_list:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use simple layout structure .. This consists of almost 4 normal layouts

Comment: i did this structure because i'm obliged and i should to have a presentation like this

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct in understand the NullPointerException is on this line?

```
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test);
```

It looks like whatever findViewById is implicitly being called on something that either doesn't have the layout you posted, or is being called before the layout has been loaded.
Could you post the rest of the code up as well?

Comment: i put the rest of the code onCreate() , in EDIT 2. I didn't put my AsyncTask , beceause , i think it's not important because it's just to fill the listView. So normaly, like i call getData() before, the LinearLayout with id : test , should be loaded

Comment: Can you tell me what line 68 is? The code you posted is only 48 lines but there is probably imports and the package name before the class declaration

Comment: Yes the lin which block, is when i do : linear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() ...

Comment: Can you check if maListViewPerso is null as well? If so, are you sure the layout in setContentView(R.layout.main) is the correct one?

Comment: The layout R.id.main , is a basic listView , and i did a custom listView.xml which is fill in AsyncTask and put in SimpleAdapter which is himself pet in setAdapter()

Comment: So the problem is that it is trying to find your test LinearLayout in the main.xml file. You need to make sure that call is done on the inflated listview.xml file

Comment: But i don't understand why , he doesn't find the LinearLayout whereas the R.id.test is in my custom listView. , in edit 3 i pet all my class, whitout asyncTask but with orther method (who works) to fill the listView

Comment: nobody can help me ? i don't stop to try and ...nothing :/

Comment: Ok so just to confirm, the listView.xml file is supposed to represent each row of the ListView right?

Comment: yes list_type_tournee.xml represent each row of my listView.